# 'read of' things vs read things

Tags: american-english

I am reading articles in New Concept English and got confused by a phrase in the below context:

> We can read of things that happened 5,000 years ago in the Near East.

here I don't understand why we use *read of*, I think we should use *read* instead of *read of*.

Comment: You can read some things, such as books.  Unless the things that happened 5,000 years ago were books (or other written material) then you probably do not read them.  You **read of** them, or **read about** them.

Comment: In this context, *of* means *about.* See 5a in M-W: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of.

Comment: Thanks GEdgar and KannE for the useful information, I got it now.